# Having trouble with showing whether $\frac{\sqrt{z^2+2z+2}}{z^2-4z+3}$ is analytic in $|z| < 2$ and / or $|z| > 2$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I'm trying to find whether

- $\frac{\sqrt{z^2+2z+2}}{z^2-4z+3}$

is analytic in $|z| < 2$ and / or $|z| > 2$.

My attempt:

So $z^2-4z+3 = 0$ when $z=1,3$ but doesn't this exclude both of the regions? Because $1<2$ and $3>2$ unless I'm missing something big

This is where I'm stuck

Edit: I'm not sure what other information I can add. That's the whole question, and I looked to find the points where the function is undefined, namely $z=1,3$ but this would exclude both regions if I'm understanding correctly

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos What? He included part of his attempt at solving it.

Comment: Your conclusion seems correct to me.

Comment: @AnneBauval Isn't the question implying at least 1 region is correct? Or am I misunderstanding the grammar

Comment: English is not my mother tongue, but math is.

Comment: @AnneBauval That's a pretty cool phrase